# Do Mox Opal + Arcbound Ravager + Scrap Trawler make an infinite combo?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it possible to do an infinite combo with those cards?

Using [Arcbound Ravager](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcbound%20Ravager%5d) I can send my [Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Opal%5d) to the graveyard. And with [Scrap Trawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bScrap%20Trawler%5d) I can take the lesser converted mana cost from my graveyard to my hand.

The question is, can I take Mox Opal? Or does Mox Opal not have a converted mana cost?

What is the Rule I can find the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mox Opal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Opal%5d) has a listed CMC on the gatherer page of 0.  So, since 0 is not less than 0, you cannot take Mox Opal back from sacrificing it.

Comment: Scrap Trawler never lets you get the same artifact back that just went to the graveyard; it doesn't matter if the CMC of that artifact is 0 or anything else.

Comment: @GendoIkari True, but if there were two opals, then it would be relevant

Comment: There are actually edge cases where you can get the same artifact back. Specifically, if an artifact is a copy of another one with greater converted mana cost, you end up comparing the CMC as the object existed on the battlefield to the CMC of the artifact card in the graveyard.

Comment: @JonTheMon Still not relevant. If the converted mana cost of an item is Y while its in play, and Y while it is in the graveyard, Scrap Trawler won't return it to your hand, because Y is not less than Y.

Comment: So what would happen with a [Sculpting steel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46720) copying a 4+CMC artifact ? Would it's ability trigger at 4+CMC while it hits the graveyard at 3, becoming a legal target to it's own trigger ? (does this question deserves it's own thread ?)

Comment: @Ydrasaal yes it would work. There was a combo a while ago with a [Phantasmal Image](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220099) copying a [Driver of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239963), it then can bring itself back.